# cordova require a plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I added this plugin  https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth  to my app:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth.git
```

I'm following their tutorial:
https://github.com/bcsphere/tutorial/blob/master/chapter01/js/index.js#L17

As far as I know the plugin's **www** folder will merged with my app's **www** folder? Then how do I correctly import the module, because

```
var BC = window.BC = cordova.require("org.bcsphere.bcjs");
```

causes the following error:

> file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/cordova.js:59
>
> Uncaught module org.bcsphere.bcjs not found

If you take a look at the plugin's **www** folder https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth/tree/master/www you can see all the available modules. I need the main: https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth/blob/master/www/org.bcsphere/bc.js

**EDIT**

I also tried `org.bcsphere.bc.js` , `org.bcsphere.bc` `org.bcsphere/bc.js`

Answer (score 0):

So I am not entirely sure because I can't try it but logically thinking it would be

```
org.bcsphere/bc.js
```

right?

Comment: Yes, but it produces the same error: "Uncaught module org.bcsphere/bc.js not found"